# Vuetify - Prepend button on the right of a text-field input

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm looking for the best practice using Vuetify to render a button on the right of a text-field (attached)

I can't seem to find it on the main [site](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/).

[image: An image of a QR code with a misaligned input and button]

```
<v-row class="text-center d-flex justify-center" v-if="downloadOption == 'HTML'">
    <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="imageLink" label="Image Link" required></v-text-field>

    <v-btn large class="ma-1" outlined color="indigo"> Copy </v-btn>

    <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="html" label="HTML" required></v-text-field>

    <v-btn large class="ma-1" outlined color="indigo"> Copy </v-btn>
</v-row>
```

Do you have any tips on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
.v-btn {
  height: 39px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="8" sm="6" class="pr-1">
            <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="html" label="HTML" required></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="4" sm="6" class="pl-0">
            <v-btn large outlined color="indigo"> Copy </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you hard code to 39px ? How you come up with 39 px ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the [`append`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#slots#append) slot in the `v-text-field` component :

```html
 <v-text-field dense v-model="html" label="HTML" required  >
     <template #append>
       <v-btn class="mb-1" outlined color="indigo"> Copy </v-btn>
     </template>             
 </v-text-field>
```

Comment: I tried your codes, and it doesn't seem to perfectly attached : https://i.imgur.com/tqtG24f.png

Comment: I was hoping to do something like button group.

Comment: this solution is good. just add mb-1 and it's good